# Why is my question unimportant? Why is it considered a trivia?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions

This question was recently closed for the reason of being "unimportant trivia":

[What is the worst month to watch movies in United States?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/24515/what-month-holds-the-record-of-bad-movies-released)

I would like to ask the community why this is. Why is it regarded as unimportant and considered trivia?

Comment: I think as someone commented on your question .... reviews are just opinion, movies are released at different times around the world even, so what is the importance of the result here?  So December 2013 (say) has the worst - so what? why is this important. People who closed the question clearly thought that is trivial information.

Comment: @iandotkelly, no you are completely wrong, if you dont like the question ok, but dont say is unimportant, it is important for me, this is QA site, if you want to see funny cats or something you may like go to facebook.

Comment: @iandotkelly, Im not surprised why this question has not been answered. It is better to use those automatic responses, which add nothing to the topic.

Comment: You asked what why the community closed it, this is my interpretation of that. Don't personalize this, no one answered your question so I decided you deserved a response.

Comment: @iandotkelly It seems not, you are a moderator, you are supposed to inform people, not give opinions. You have to substantiate your answers. You have been given a power that must be used correctly.

Comment: I'm sorry your question isn't considered on topic by the community - I really am, and I was just passing on my interpretation of the general feeling of the community here towards 'trivia' questions, you can try to modify the question to re-inforce the general interest/importance of the answer, or use meta to try to convince the community to change its overall stance as to the question of trivia.

Comment: On the subject of moderation - I actually make quite a point about reflecting the general will of the community, and would personally take a more open viewpoint on trivia.  If you wish to take this up with me in chat I would be happy to discuss further.

Comment: @iandotkelly, Wrong again, one person can't speak for all. I'm going to stop this here, because you don't give solutions.

Comment: Never claimed to speak for all - just claimed to try to reflect the community here even if it doesn't entirely match my own opinion.  Happy to discuss solutuons you might wish to see - but I seriously can't change the 'will of the community' just because one user doesn't like what is on/off-topic.

Comment: That being said I'm not sure I would have closed it as trivia (even though it doesn't interest me personally, we have many other such "record"-type questions which are totally valid), but rather as *"primarily opinion-based"* (but I'm not sure about that either) seeing that the question is centered around statistics but it's hard to assess what "bad" means in this case. Maybe an even more vague question centering not so much around simple statistics but a proper analysis of release strategies might have worked better and might not have attracted so much disapproval for being too "trivia"...

Comment: ...But I don't want to dictate the question you ask either. If it's statistics you want to see, then I'm not supposed to alter your question into a completely different direction. That being said I at least tried to clean up the question a bit, including the point from *BenPlont*'s comment (instead of just writing *"read the comment to know why this question is good"*) and removing the statement that said *"please don't downvote"*, which might actually have the contrary effect of making people aware that the question *might* be strange.